# React Audio visualizer and video player not working in react (plays infinitly the audio and the audio visualizer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

i have this component i have that displays a simple audio visualizer:
// AudioVisualizer.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const AudioVisualizer = ({ audioSrc, onPlay, onPause, onEnded }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [audioPlaying, setAudioPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [audioContext, setAudioContext] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let analyser;
    let source;

    const initializeAudioContext = () => {
      const newAudioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      analyser = newAudioContext.createAnalyser();
      source = newAudioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);

      source.connect(analyser);
      analyser.connect(newAudioContext.destination);

      analyser.fftSize = 256;
      const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
      const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

      const drawVisualizer = () => {
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const barWidth = (canvas.width / bufferLength) * 2.5;
        let barHeight;
        let x = 0;

        dataArray.forEach((value) => {
          barHeight = value;

          ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(0, ${barHeight + 100}, 0)`;
          ctx.fillRect(x, canvas.height - barHeight / 2, barWidth, barHeight / 2);

          x += barWidth + 1;
        });

        if (audioPlaying) {
          requestAnimationFrame(drawVisualizer);
        }
      };

      audio.addEventListener('play', () => {
        setAudioPlaying(true);
        onPlay && onPlay();
        drawVisualizer();
      });

      audio.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        setAudioPlaying(false);
        onPause && onPause();
      });

      audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        setAudioPlaying(false);
        onEnded && onEnded();
      });
    };

    const audio = new Audio(audioSrc);

    audio.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
      // Initialize the AudioContext when the audio is ready to play
      if (!audioContext) {
        setAudioContext(true);
        initializeAudioContext();
      }
    });

    return () => {
      audio.pause();
      audioContext && audioContext.close();
    };
  }, [audioSrc, onPlay, onPause, onEnded, audioPlaying, audioContext]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={300} height={100} />;
};

export default AudioVisualizer;
```

and this page that should display it:

```
import AudioVisualizer from "../../components/audioPlayer/audioPlayer"
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function(){ 
  const [audioPlaying, setAudioPlaying] = useState(false);

   return (
                <div className='flex gap-2'>
    <AudioVisualizer
      audioSrc="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3"
      onPlay={() => setAudioPlaying(true)}
  onPause={() => setAudioPlaying(false)}
  onEnded={() => setAudioPlaying(false)}
  color="#00000"
    />
    <ReactAudioPlayer
      src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3"
      controls
      playing={audioPlaying}
    />
  </div>
  )
}
```

What i want is the audiovisualizer to be displayed only when i click play on reactaudioplayer and stop/pause it when i click stop or pause. But i don't see my error here, maybe it's something very silly but i'm really not seeing the problem.
I think that it has something to do with this part maybe:

```
audio.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
  // Call the provided onPlay callback when the audio starts playing
  onPlay && onPlay();
  audio.play();
  drawVisualizer();
});
```

i don't really know can someone please help me, i'm really stuck.